# ant, referring from one property value to another

Tags: java, ant, properties, reference

I have a  task inside of my init target that creates a property named "TODAY" :

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="TODAY" pattern="kk:mm:ss-MM-dd-yyyy" locale="en,US"/>
</tstamp>
```

And a property for where I want my built files to reside named "store.dir" :

```
<property name="store.dir" value="target/${TODAY}"/>
```

This is ideally what I want... the store.dir property referring to the TODAY property so that I can retarget where I want my packages to be put by modifying one property instead of going through every single jar task.

This doesn't seem to be working though... an echo yields this :

```
 [echo] Making dir : target/${TODAY}
```

Am I just using the wrong construct here? If I separate them and put them into the dir paths/etc it seems to resolve the properties fine(as it should).

Entire relevant section of my config:

```
   <property name="store.dir" value="target/${TODAY}"/>
   <target name="init">
          <tstamp>
            <format property="TODAY" pattern="kk:mm:ss-MM-dd-yyyy" locale="en,US"/>
          </tstamp>
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <mkdir dir="doc"/>
        <echo>Making dir : ${store.dir}</echo>
        <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="JUnit">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
```

Comment: Are those two lines in the same file?

Comment: Yes they are, I've updated the OP with the relevant section of the build xml

Comment: Uuh, your `store.dir` is declared _after_ `TODAY`... I believe your problem is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works :

```
<project>
  <tstamp>
      <format property="TODAY" pattern="kk:mm:ss-MM-dd-yyyy" locale="en,US"/>
  </tstamp>

  <property name="store.dir" value="target/${TODAY}"/>

  <echo>$${store.dir} => ${store.dir}</echo>
</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] ${store.dir} => target/22:13:07-03-17-2014
```

Maybe the target that want's to use the property store.dir doesn't have the init target in it's dependency chain ?

**-- EDIT after comment and Edit of original question --**
As fge already mentioned in his comment, your property declaration of store.dir happens before calling the tstamp task which can't work. Fix it like that :

```
<target name="init">
 <tstamp>
  <format property="TODAY" pattern="kk:mm:ss-MM-dd-yyyy" locale="en,US"/>
 </tstamp>
 <property name="store.dir" value="target/${TODAY}"/>
...
</target>
```

Comment: Hm, I actually put the echo task right after the tstamp task... I'll update the main post with my entire init target